# Upload a file to S3 and set its storage class with boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload a file to S3 and set its storage class with boto, but I can't find the list of strings/constants to use to specify the storage class.  I want to do something like:

```
s3_client.upload_file(file, bucket, key, ExtraArgs={'StorageClass': 'GLACIER'})
```

What is the list of possible strings I can use in the place of 'GLACIER' above? It must be documented somewhere, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it in `aws-cli` help [online](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) or from command line:

```
aws s3 cp help
```

Related command line parameter is `--storage-class` and (as of today) documentation says:

> --storage-class (string) The type of storage to use for the object. Valid choices are: STANDARD | REDUCED_REDUNDANCY | STANDARD_IA | ONEZONE_IA | INTELLIGENT_TIERING | GLACIER | DEEP_ARCHIVE. Defaults to 'STANDARD'